# Photo editor for Windows 10 for cropping and resizing (like mac preview app)

Tags: macos, windows-10, editor, photo, preview

I have been using the default photo viewer of mac to perform following workflow. Any suggestion for a lightweight photo editor to get the same results with a few clicks in a windows 10 machine?

Workflow steps:
1. Open photo
2. Copy the entire photo or a partial selection to clipboard.
3. resize the canvas (800x800)
4. Apply a white background by creating a white rectangle on top of the original photo
5. Paste the photo copied photo from the clipboard on the white background. Canvas size remains 800x800.
6. Move or resize the pasted photo, so that it fits into the canvas.
7. Save and overwrite the original photo.

Answer (score 0):

I've just recently started using Gravit designer it's quite awesome tool for templating designs but I'm pretty sure you can work with it for anything especially regarding vector based graphics. It's easy to get the gist of, light weight and you can get it for free on windows 10  just by taking a look at the Microsoft app store. No trials or extra functionality via purchase. Enjoy!